# Wrapping within inline child elements, instead of between them

Tags: html, css

Please refer to this image from the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/dn9tt26e/

[image]

How do I prevent wrapping just after the

```
<i>(03/10/2016) Author Name</i>
```

element so that each line (except perhaps the last) always takes the full width of the container?.

The following image from the https://jsfiddle.net/hzsb8wr3/2/ was proposed as a solution; it works in Chrome, but it shows a break (in Firefox) before the last slash in the date (03/10/2016) 
[image]

But I don't want the text to break at all in the middle of a line; in order words, all lines of content (except perhaps the last) should fill the horizontal width of the container.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. It's unclear.

Comment: What is unclear about the question? Did you actually look at the fiddle? I don't want the text to break immediately after the inner <i> element, because there is still space after it. In other words, I want the whole inner content to flow as if it were a single element, breaking only when it exceed the horizontal length of its container

Answer (score 0):

The word is breaking at the space because it is considered an "acceptable break". The only way I can think of to get around this is to add in a non breaking space `&nbsp;` instead. e.g.

```
<i>(03/10/2016)&nbsp;Author&nbsp;Name</i>&nbsp;yoursuperlongtextstring
```

This will mean there is no acceptable break so it will use the css you have implemented with `overflow-wrap` and `word-wrap` to break at the end of the line.

Update: Here is a demo forked from your original fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hzsb8wr3/2/

Update: added screenshot.[image]

Comment: Worked for me? You actually only need word-wrap and overflow-wrap, and you definitely don't need the important.. but either way it worked, unless i've interpreted your question incorrectly. Which is possible. Anyway here is a fork of your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hzsb8wr3/2/

Comment: OK, in your fiddle, I can see that the content does not wrap after the <i> element, but it does break after after the last slash in the date. I don't want the text to break at all in the middle of line; in order words, all lines of content (except perhaps the last) should fill the horizontal width of the container

Comment: I've added a screenshot for what i'm see in my fiddle (edited my answer for reference). This is how i've interpreted your question. Is that not what you want? Or is that not what you see? It's possible that whatever browser you are looking in interprets what is an acceptable break differently. I'm using chrome. You could possibly get around this by putting a nonbreaking space after in between the forward slashes.

Comment: I checked again in Chrome, and it works, but not in Firefox (see the second image in my edited question). It does not wrap at all in IE 11.

Comment: And if I add another non-breaking space in between the slashes, it works, but then of course it is not the same content because of the unwanted spaces